# i am getting error in migration ef core using mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

i am migrating postgresql to mysl.

I have chaged to this

```
    services.AddDbContext<CPSContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySQL(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(CPSContext).Assembly.FullName)));
```

> PM> update-database Build started... Build succeeded.
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Specified key was
> too long; max key length is 3072 bytes    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
> Int64& insertedId)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32
> statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
> force)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject
> parameterObject)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection
> connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1
> migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
> targetMigration)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

Configuration like below

```
  public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Branch> builder)
        {
            base.Configure(builder);
            builder.ToTable("branch", schema: "public");
            builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
            builder.Property(b => b.Code).HasMaxLength(20);
            builder.Property(b => b.Name).HasMaxLength(100);
            builder.Property(b => b.Address1).HasMaxLength(200);
            builder.Property(b => b.Address2).HasMaxLength(200);
            builder.Property(b => b.Address3).HasMaxLength(200);

            builder.HasOne(b => b.Bank).WithMany(ba => ba.Branches).HasForeignKey(b => b.BankId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);



            //Data Seed

            builder.HasData(
              new Branch() { Id = 1, Name = "B1", BIN = "1", Code = "B1", RecieptName = "Br1", BankId = 1, BranchTypeId = 1, Address1 = "A1", Address2 = "A2", DefaultAgentPassword = "Agent@123", DefaultStaffPassword = "Staff@123", Created = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = AuthorizationConstants.DEFAULT_SUPER_ADMIN_USERID },
              new Branch() { Id = 2, Name = "B2", BIN = "2", Code = "B2", RecieptName = "Br1", BankId = 1, BranchTypeId = 1, Address1 = "A1", Address2 = "A2", DefaultAgentPassword = "Agent@123", DefaultStaffPassword = "Staff@123", Created = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = AuthorizationConstants.DEFAULT_SUPER_ADMIN_USERID }
          );
        }
```

But i am getting error in my sql data migration ..please let meknow

Comment: How do you know that it is definitely this table definition to which the error relates?

Comment: i dont no..i which error  has occured..do u have any idea? am using long datatype also...how to check  that..am new to mysql ..pls hel

Comment: I'm just wondering which one of your tables has a string primary key.. it doesn't appear to be this one

Comment: @CaiusJard am not used string in entire application either int or long only

Comment: Have you got any tables where you've made indexes that include large columns?

Comment: public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserLogin> builder)
        {
            
            builder.HasKey(ul => new { ul.LoginProvider, ul.ProviderKey });
        }  Is there any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core 2.0 with MySQL: Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66440090/5519026)

Comment: Thanks @LaxZiya for both helping..@lazziya ur link works ...